# How to implement RingFiFoBuffer

Tags: java, buffer, fifo, circular-buffer

I'm new to Java programming. I have several questions about how to implement RingFiFoBuffer:

1. Can I store big XML files into this buffer? If yes how big?
2. Can several threads insert/delete/fetch records from the RingBuffer simultaneously?
3. How many records can I store?
4. Is there any tutorial that I can see how to write the code.

I only found http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 and 3: That is only limited by the memory you assign to the Java process that executes your program.

Qestion 2: Accessing a Collection like the referenced CircularFifoBuffer usually requires to "synchronize" them. The linked JavaDoc already contains the code for synchronizing it:

```
Buffer fifo = BufferUtils.synchronizedBuffer(new CircularFifoBuffer());
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I store big XML files into this buffer? If yes how big?

You are only limited by your disk space with memory mapped files.

> Can several threads insert/delete/fetch records from the RingBuffer simultaneously?

That depends on your implementation.  Usually ring buffers are shared between threads.

> How many records can I store?

This is something you usually limit when you create the ring buffer so its up to you. Its usually sensible to keep these to a minimum as larger ring buffers can often be slower than tighter ring buffers.  So the practical limit may depend on your application and the hardware used.

> Is there any tutorial that I can see how to write the code.

The best example I know is the Disruptor library.  Its pretty advanced but has better documentation than any I can think of. (Including libraries I have written ;)

http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/